# Can inactive Broadcast Receivers be reused?

Tags: android, process, broadcastreceiver, spawn

Let's say a BroadcastReceiver is declared in the manifest. It has run through onReceive() once and is the only component in the hosting process. What if another Intent is broadcast, is a new process spawn every time, or would the old one be reused if it hasn't been killed?

In other words: Is the onReceive()-method only run through ONCE for each receiver object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would the old one be reused if it hasn't been killed?

No.

> Is the onReceive()-method only run through ONCE for each receiver object?

Yes, for manifest-registered receivers.

Comment: Ok. So the lifecycle of a receiver instance is not bound to the application if it's not dynamically created. Thanks!